# Desktop icons disappear after hibernation

Tags: gnome-shell, hibernate, gnome-shell-extension, desktop-icons

Very often, some of my desktop icons (`.desktop` files I have created) disappear after I close the lid and hibernate the computer. Quite annoying I'd say. These icons (and the Applications menu from a well-written Gnome-shell extension by Florian Müllner) are my favourite ways to start applications (unless I type in a console of course). I live happily without any dock/launcher or whatever it's called; that one is always in the way in any case.

I have found that by locking/unlocking the screen (<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) the icons reappear, but otherwise this is a mystery to me. Any help greatly appreciated :)

BTW: Ubuntu 20.04, HP Pavilion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icons on the desktop in Ubuntu 19.04 and later releases are handled by a GNOME Shell extension (as opposed to the file manager Nautilus in older releases) called "Desktop Icons" (package  name: `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons`).

As per GNOME's security policy *all* the extensions get disabled once you lock your screen or suspend or hibernate; and they are re-enabled after you log back in. It seems sometimes in your case somehow the extension fails to reload properly after returning from a hibernation. Then another screen locking followed by unlocking disables and restores the extension correctly once again.

As another workaround, when you find the icons missing, restart GNOME shell by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then typing `r` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> (note: this does *not* work in a Wayland session). This should bring back the icons.